# Remove word within a string based on another columns value

Tags: python, pandas, string, string-comparison

I have two columns that is a combination of comma separated words and single words in a string format. `col1` will always only contain one word. In this example I will use the word *Dog* as the word to have in `col1`, but this will differ in the real data, so please do not make a solution that uses regex on *Dog* specifically.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["Dog", "Dog", "Dog", "Dog"],
                     "col2": ["Cat, Mouse", "Dog", "Cat", "Dog, Mouse"]})
```

I want to check if the word in `col1` appears in the string in `col2`, and if it does, I want to remove that word from `col2`. But keep in mind that I want to keep the rest of the string if there are more words left. So it will go from this:

```
    col1    col2    
0   Dog     Cat, Mouse
1   Dog     Dog
2   Dog     Cat
3   Dog     Dog, Mouse
```

To this:

```
    col1    col2
0   Dog     Cat, Mouse
1   Dog 
2   Dog     Cat
3   Dog     Mouse
```

Comment: IMHO, just go through data iteratively then use `string.replace` i.e. `x.replace('Dog', '')`

Comment: Did you read the question? That solution is not reproducible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(^,|,$)` *to handle starting & trailing comma*

`(,\s|,)` *will remove comma those getting retained after replace operation.*

`{1,}` *to skip non-repeated comma*

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str. \
    replace("|".join(df['col1'].unique()), "").str.strip() \
    .str.replace("(?:^,|,$)", "") \
    .str.replace("(?:,\s|,){1,}", ",")

  col1          col2
0  Dog     Cat,Mouse
1  Dog              
2  Dog           Cat
3  Dog   Mouse,Mouse
```

Comment: What if _Dog_ appears in the middle of the string or in the end of the string? This will leave me with some excess commas. Sorry I did not specify this in the question

Comment: @torkestativ, is ```col1``` going to have single value or multiple values ?

Comment: it will have a single value, @Sushanth

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import re
df['col2'] = [(re.sub(fr"({word}[\s,]*)","",sentence)) 
             for word,sentence in zip(df.col1,df.col2)]
df

    col1    col2
0   Dog     Cat, Mouse
1   Dog 
2   Dog     Cat
3   Dog     Mouse
```

another df, with dog in the middle :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["Dog", "Dog", "Dog", "Dog","Dog"],
                     "col2": ["Cat, Mouse", "Dog", "Cat", "Dog, Mouse", "Cat, Dog, Mouse"]})

df


   col1     col2
0   Dog     Cat, Mouse
1   Dog     Dog
2   Dog     Cat
3   Dog     Dog, Mouse
4   Dog     Cat, Dog, Mouse
```

Apply the code above :

```
   col1     col2
0   Dog     Cat, Mouse
1   Dog 
2   Dog     Cat
3   Dog     Mouse
4   Dog     Cat, Mouse
```

Answer (score 1):

`l=df.col1.tolist()`#list of col1

Create set from `col2`, evaluate membership of `l` in set by finding difference applying lambda function.

```
df['col2']=list(zip(df.col2))
df['col2']=df.col2.apply(lambda x:[*{*x}-{*l}]).str[0]
```

[image]